# create a view and concatenate more than one field to single field name

Tags: mysql, view

i want to create a view from two table, **members** table and **assets** table,
and concatinate name from members table as one field **INCHARGE**

here is my code
     $host="localhost";
     $db="ccm_db";
     $pass="";
     $user="root";

```
 $conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or
 die("cannot connect to the        database".mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($db,$conn)or 
 die("cannot select the database".mysql_error());


 mysql_query("select a.asset_name as ASSET_NAME,
             m.(a.fname,' ',a.mname,' ',a.lname) as INCHARGE from asset a,members m");
```

i want this so as to have a fullname when i export to exel.

any help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a join in order to get a combined result from two tables, like in

```
select a.asset_name as ASSET_NAME
       CONCAT(a.fname, ' ', a.mname, ' ', a.lname) as INCHARGE
from asset a, members m
where a.member = m.id
```

Or similar. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)